# Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory Ionic 3 prod build

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, npm, ionic3

I am getting the following error when i am building a prod build of my Ionic 3 app. 
"**FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory**"
To reproduce this issue i made a copy of the entire project and made a prod build in the copied project but surprisingly the prod build was generated. I am unable to find what is exactly causing this issue.

I am attaching my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Fusion",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/qr-scanner": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/spinner-dialog": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/toast": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/transfer": "^3.14.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.32",
    "buffer": "^5.2.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "cldr-data": "^36.0.0",
    "concat-stream": "^1.6.2",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-native-spinner": "^1.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-qrscanner": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-toast": "^2.7.2",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "devextreme": "19.1.10",
    "devextreme-angular": "19.1.10",
    "events": "^3.0.0",
    "globalize": "^1.4.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "iana-tz-data": "^2019.1.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-select-searchable": "^2.10.0",
    "ionic-selectable": "^3.4.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jszip": "^3.1.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-soap": "^0.5.0-beta.7",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.8.4",
    "primeicons": "^1.0.0",
    "primeng": "^5.2.7",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sax": "^1.2.4",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "tracking": "^1.1.3",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.1",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.6.2",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.4.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^13.13.4",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-qrscanner": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-native-spinner": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-toast": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
     "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am getting this issue constantly on my project but not on the copied one. Both the projects have the same package.json and code.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your application consumes more memory than default allocated one.
There are two things that you can do

1. Refactor your project and try to optimise it, remove all unnecessary libraries and imports, it will reduce the load on angular compiler while building the bundle.
2. First point is not helpful many times and you may need a quick solution, so you can increase the heap memory allocation by using `node --max_old_space_size=8192 $which(ionic-app-scripts) build` or `node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/bin/ionic-app-scripts.js build`

and for the point that it worked in copied project - may be your system resources are not that busy at that point of time

Comment: Okay, I'll try to optimize my Project.

Comment: Hey! The commands that you gave works but it doesn't make an android prod build apk. I guess it just builds the project. How can i use it  to generate prod build apk?

Comment: First build using those command then use `ionic cordova build android --no-build` I guess this will use your existing build that you made using earlier commands